Embed stripe checkout on website with next js
I want to integrate stripe payment with embedded form in my nextjs project. Since it's a new addition to Stripe, I'm not finding resources how to do it. There is an official documentation but it's not working properly. I'd be grateful if someone help me do it.
Here is the official documentation: https://docs.stripe.com/checkout/embedded/quickstart
My Api route: 'api/checkout_sessions'
 const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  switch (req.method) {
    case "POST":
      try {
        const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
          ui_mode: 'embedded',
          line_items: [
            {
              price: 'price_1P5p2nIrKwv2F1FvTIPuwNwF',
              quantity: 1,
            },
          ],
          mode: 'payment',
          return_url:
            `${req.headers.origin}/return?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
        });

    res.send({clientSecret: session.client_secret});
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(err.statusCode || 500).json(err.message);
  }
  break;
case "GET":
  try {
    const session =
      await stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve(req.query.session_id);

    res.send({
      status: session.status,
      customer_email: session.customer_details.email
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(err.statusCode || 500).json(err.message);
  }
  break;
default:
  res.setHeader('Allow', req.method);
  res.status(405).end('Method Not Allowed');
  }
}

This is the error I'm getting:


https://sultanoveli.medium.com/how-to-add-stripe-payments-to-your-next-js-app-d1cfced7c8a5   check this link

What is your code and what is not working?

What is not working? Can you share the code and error messages?

Please have a look at the details. I've added the code

You need to share complete code like also the frontend that calls that endpoint and what it does.

The error probably means there's something wrong with your authentication(your Stripe keys), for instance you are using the publishable key of a different Stripe account on the frontend than one who's secret key you're using on the backend; or you're using livemode keys in the backend and testmode in the frontend, or vice versa or so on.
